# Facebook Login using php sdk goes on loop

Tags: php, facebook, exception, authentication, oauth

I'm trying to log and register an user into my db when he presses on my link in index.php . I searched all over the internet for an answer. I worked on this code for over 4 days and I wrote it in many ways but none of them solved this oauthexception problem caused by the token. So I put it in a loop and sometimes it works. Why? Why sometimes it works and sometimes not?

This is my fbLogin.php

```
session_start();
if(!(isset($_SESSION['fb']))){
    $fb=new FbConnection();
    $url=$fb->getLoginUrl();
    $_SESSION['fb']=$fb;
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}
$fb=$_SESSION['fb'];
try{
$fbUser=$fb->getUser();
}catch(Exception $e){
    sleep(3);
    header("Location: fbLogin.php");
    exit;
```

}

This is my FbConnection

```
class FbConnection{
    private $facebook;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->facebook=new Facebook(array(
            'appId'     => '******',
            'secret'    => '*******',
            ));         
    }

    public function getUser(){
        $user=$this->facebook->getUser();
        if($user){
            try {
                $this->facebook->api('/me');
                }catch(Exception $e){
                    print("errore preso<br>");
                    error_log($e);
                    $user = null;
                    //self::reloadToken();
                    }
        }
        $user=$this->facebook->api('/me');
        $name=$user['first_name'];
        $lastName=$user['last_name'];
        $email=$user['email'];
        $sex=$user['gender'];
        $birthday=$user['birthday'];
        $res=$this->facebook->api('me?fields=third_party_id');
        $tpid=$res['third_party_id'];
        //print($tpid."<br>");
        $fbUser=new FacebookUser($name, $lastName, $email, $sex, $birthday, $tpid);
        return $fbUser;

    }    

    public function getConnectionStatus(){
        if($_SESSION['user']->third_party_id)
            return true;
        return false;   
    }
    public function connect(){
        if($_SESSION['user']->third_party_id)
            throw new FacebookAlreadyConnectedException('Questo account è già associato ad un account Facebook');
        $fbUser=$this->getUser();
        $user=$_SESSION['user'];
        $result=UserManager::searchByContent('third_party_id', $fbUser->third_party_id);
        if($result) throw new FacebookAlreadyRegisteredException('Questo account Facebook è già registrato');
        else
        $user->third_party_id=$fbUser->third_party_id;

    }

    public function getLogoutUrl(){
        if(!self::getConnectionStatus())
            return 'index.php';
        $params = array( 'next' => *****' );
        return $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl($params); // $params is optional.
    }

    public function getLoginUrl(){
        $params=array('scope' => 'email, user_birthday',
  'redirect_uri' => ***/fbLogin.php);
            return $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
        }

        }
```

And this is the link code on index.php

Accedi tramite Facebook

What's the problem? It sometimes goes on loop and sometimes it works.

The loop is in the try/catch block because of the oAuthException thrown by fb->getUser() calling facebook->api class method with an invalid token. It goes on loop because it redirects again on the page trying to get a new token. But how may I get a valid token?

Comment: I can't see the loop you're talking about. Also, it's unclear to me where in the code your oauthexception is raised.

Comment: The loop is in the try/catch block because of the oAuthException thrown by fb->getUser() calling facebook->api class method with an invalid token. It goes on loop because it redirects again on the page trying to get a new token. But how may I get a valid token?

Comment: So what exception does it throw?

Comment: "I worked on this code for over 4 days" --- facebook php sdk is shipped with **WORKED** example. Try to start with it instead

Comment: I've tryed. Always the same... The exception is "OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user"